# Does printf have an "engineering" notation format for numbers?

Tags: printf

Say I have this number: 105000000, in this form I can't easily see how big it is, so using `printf` at a prompt I try using the "scientific" notation:

```
% printf "%.3E" 105000000
1.050E+08
```

This is better but I would like to use an "engineering" notation where the output is formatted in powers of 10<sup>3</sup> millions, billions, trillions etc.
e.g. I want to format it to look like this:

```
105000        => 105.0E+03      (105 thousand)
105000000     => 105.0E+06      (105 million)
105000000000  => 105.0E+09      (105 billion)
...
```

can `printf` do this?

Comment: no it doesn't, but it's been implemented several times - for example https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/c/eng.html (I did it as part of a plotting package in the [1970s](https://invisible-island.net/personal/oldprogs.html#y1977)) - Fortran, of course.

Comment: @ThomasDickey nice! ... i'd like to get the same in python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know of any `printf` implementation that does. Note that POSIX doesn't even guarantee `printf '%E\n' 123` to work at all as support for floating point formats is optional.

With several `printf` implementations, you can use `%'f` to output thousand separators in locales that have one:

```
$ LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8 printf "%'.0f\n" 105000000
105,000,000
$ LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8 printf "%'.0f\n" 105000000
105 000 000
$ LC_NUMERIC=da_DK.UTF-8 printf "%'.0f\n" 105000000
105.000.000
$ LC_NUMERIC=de_CH.UTF-8 printf "%'.0f\n" 105000000
105'000'000
$ LC_NUMERIC=ps_AF.UTF-8 printf "%'.0f\n" 105000000
105٬000٬000
```

With the `printf` builtin of `ksh93`, you can also use `%#d` for K/M/G... suffixes and `%#i` for Ki/Mi/Gi ones:

```
$ printf '%#d\n' 105000000 $((2**22))
105M
4.2M
$ printf '%#i\n' 105000000 $((2**22))
100Mi
4.0Mi
```

(note however that you can't change the precision and the transition from  `Ki` to `Mi` for instance is at 1000 Ki, not 1024 Ki which can be surprising if you're used to the GNU format (like in GNU `ls -lh`). It's also limited to **integer** numbers up to 2<sup>63</sup>-1 (8Ei - 1)).

As to how to implement it by hand, with `zsh`:

```
eng() {
  local n="${(j: :)argv}" exp
  zmodload zsh/mathfunc
  if ((n)) && ((exp = int(floor(log10(abs(n)) / 3)) * 3)); then
    printf '%.10ge%d\n' "n / 1e$exp" exp
  else
    printf '%.10g\n' "$n"
  fi
}
```

And then:

```
$ eng 123
123
$ eng 12345
12.345e3
$ eng 0.000000123123
123.123e-9
$ eng 1. / -1234
-810.3727715e-6
```

Note that in `zsh` like in many other languages, operations involving floats are done in floating point arithmetics (with your processor's `double` type) while those involving integers only are done in integer arithmetics (with your processor's `long` type). That has some implications like:

```
$ eng 1  / -1234
0
$ eng 1. / -1234
-810.3727715e-6
```

but also:

```
$ eng 1 \*{2..28}.  # factorial 28
304.8883446e27
$ eng 1 \*{2..28}
-5.968160533e18  # 64bit signed integer overflow
```

(though that's not specific to that `eng` function)

Or as a POSIX shell function using POSIX `bc`, so allowing arbitrary precision:

```
eng() (
  IFS=" "
  scale=$1; shift
  bc -l << EOF |
  s = scale = $scale
  if (scale < 20) s = 20
  n = $*
  if (n != 0) {
    scale = s
    a = n; if (a < 0) a = -a
    e = l(a) / l(10) / 3 + 10 ^ -15
    if (e < 0) e -= 1
    scale = 0
    e = e / 1 * 3
    scale = s
    if (scale <= -e) scale = 1 - e
    n = n / 10^e
    scale = $scale
  }
  n/1
  if (e != 0) e
EOF
    sed '
      :1
      /\\$/{
        N;b1
      }
      s/\\\n//g
      /\./s/0*$//
      s/\.$//
      $!N
      s/\n/e/'
)
```

(with a 1e-15 shift to offset rounding errors when calculating log10(n) for the exponent for values of n like 0.001)

Here with the first argument being taken as the *scale*:

```
$ eng 2 1/3
330e-3
$ eng 20 1/3
333.33333333333333333e-3
```

Note that `bc` itself doesn't understand the engineering notation, you have to write:

```
$ eng 20 "1.123123 * 10^2000"
112.3123e1998
```

Comment: thanks, using `%'f` to format into thousands separators is really useful to know, as it covers most of the situations I would have needed an engineering notation for.