# Scientific notations to specific scientific notation

Tags: linux, shell-script, numeric-data

I want to convert the value from 1.759114e-07 to 175.9114e-09. How can I script the conversion?

I tried this but I'm not getting what I want (which is 175.9114e-09):

```bash
$ echo 1.759114e-07 | awk '{printf("%.3g\n", $1*1e2 ) }'
1.76e-05
```

Comment: See [Does printf have an "engineering" notation format for numbers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/394872/170373).

Comment: The question is whether all the awk flavors share the same limitations of `printf` in that answer.

Comment: @RobertSmith The main task in the question is to produce a number on the correct form. The user shows their attept at do so by using `awk`. This does not mean that the question is about `awk`, or that an answer need to use `awk`.  In fact, it's not even tagged with `awk`, nor does it mention `awk` in the text.  If the user comes back to clarify their question, it would possibly make sense to re-open the issue. If you have a question about this that is not answered by the duplicate, then feel free to post a separate question.

Comment: @Kusalananda I just thought it was an interesting question and if clarification was needed, asking the user first whether awk is relevant to his question is a better policy than closing the question as a duplicate. I suspect awk is relevant here because of the very specific calculation. Otherwise, the user would have shown a much simpler example with bash's printf just to exemplify the concept.

Comment: @RobertSmith What usually happens is that the original user comes back saying "no, the duplicate does not answer my question because (specific reason)". This has not (yet) happened in this case.

Comment: @Kusalananda Fair enough.